# Does ASP.NET Core version have to match nuget package versions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to work out which version of the ASP.NET related packages I should be using.

We are trying to stick to LTS versions of ASP.NET Core, meaning we are still on version 2.1 and not 2.2 for the compiler and runtime. However I'm having a hard to trying to find out what version of the nuget packages we should be using.

for example, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc says that its latest version is 2.2.0 and visual studio wants me to upgrade to this. However, I am wondering if we should stay on 2.1.3 since we are still on 2.1 for the compiler.

Are these version numbers related? Should we be staying back on 2.1.x to match pace with the compiler or are we doing things wrong?

Comment: Use `global.json` in the project to explicit using .NET Core 2.1 SDK should avoid all unnecessary things. You should only have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in your project file (version of 2.1.x or no version at all). .NET Core 2.1 should automatically resolve all the other packages needed.